# Suspend and resume SharePoint Online workflow using CSOM - Ecmascript

Tags: workflow, javascript, sharepoint-online

I have a requirement where the Master user has power to interrupt any workflow and put it on hold and the approvals should be stopped on that workflow until the Master user resumes the workflow.

When creating a CSOM project and writing code in C#, I could find methods 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.workflowservices.workflowinstanceservice.suspendworkflow(v=office.15).aspx

As `WorkflowInstanceService.SuspendWorkflow` and `WorkflowInstanceService.ResumeWorkflow`. However I need to use these methods with CSOM - EcmaScript.

I am able to `terminateWorkflow` using JavaScript. However for Suspend and Resume it doesn't work.

Anyone having success in `SuspendWorkflow` and `ResumeWorkflow` using JavaScript object model?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do it from JS. The code will be something like this:

```
(function () {


    var workflowInstanceId = 'PUT-YOUR-GUID-HERE';

    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();

    var servicesManager = SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.newObject(context, web);

    var instance = servicesManager.getWorkflowInstanceService().getInstance(workflowInstanceId);

    servicesManager.getWorkflowInstanceService().suspendInstance(instance);
    // or servicesManager.getWorkflowInstanceService().resumeInstance(instance);

    context.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, args) {

        alert('Instance was suspended successfully!');

    },
    function (sender, args) {
        alert("Error occured! " + args.get_message() + 
                 '\r\nStack trace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
    });

})();
```

If you don't know the workflow instance ID, you can enumerate all the instances e.g. for a list item, using method `enumerateInstancesForListItem(listId, itemId)` of the WorkflowInstanceService.

Also you can determine if the workflow is suspended or is running at the moment by getting the instance (don't forget `context.load(instance)`, and then inside executeQueryAsync success callback you can use it) and then analysing the `get_status()` property of the instance. Possible status values are stored in the `SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowStatus` enumeration.

Useful resources:

1. [Using SharePoint Workflow Services JS API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607127/Using-SharePoint-Workflow-Services-JS-API) (from CodeProject)
2. [Annotated definition for WorkflowServices.js SharePoint file](https://sptypescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Definitions/SP.WorkflowServices.d.ts)

Disclaimer: both the article and the definition were authored by me.